# bootpag event runs several times when used after a returned Ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pagination

I am using [bootpag](https://github.com/botmonster/jquery-bootpag/blob/master/lib/jquery.bootpag.js) jQuery pagination plugin in my .NET/jQuery project. In my project I have a filtering menu. When the user clicked on one of the filtering options, I run an Ajax call to the server which updates the page with the new filtered/paged data.

I initialize the bootpag in the ".done" ajax function, right after the ajax called is returned.

Here's the bootpag code

```
 $.ajax({
   // some ajax call data info here to get the filtered results
  }).done(function(data){

     $("#paging").bootpag({     
        total: (data.totalResults / CONST_RESULTS_PER_PAGE) + 1
       }).on('page', function (event, num) {
          updateListWithFilteredResults(num);
       });
  });
```

The problem is that when bootpag detects a page click, it runs the same function (as I told it too)  that contains that ajax call with that same code in it. It causes the 'page' event to be binded several times. So when I click a page the third time, it will run the on 'page' event three times, and so forth.

I need to init bootpag after the ajax call because this is where I have the total results, which I use to initialize bootpag plugin (with some other data as well, but total pages is the most important property to init bootpag).

How can I solve this, and only make the event run once? I prefer a non hackish solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have to do much with bootpag, however. As you mentioned init of a page and a repeated user action, handling of ajax request in two cases should differ.

```
function refreshData() {
    return $.ajax({
        // some ajax call data info here to get the filtered results
    }).then(function (data) {
        return $("#paging").bootpag({
            total: (data.totalResults / CONST_RESULTS_PER_PAGE) + 1
        });
    });
}

//on init of page do
refreshData().then(function (bootpag) {
    bootpag.on('page', function (event, num) {
        updateListWithFilteredResults(num);
    });
});

//on user click just
refreshData();
```